# Scrolling issue with UITableViewController hosted in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have the following setup in my app:

```
UITabBarController
 UINavigationController
  UIViewController
```

The UIViewController has a UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling.
In the cells, I want to "host" a view from another ViewController. This works pretty well, but I have scrolling issues. The first UICollectionViewCell hosts a view that comes from a UITableViewController. I can scroll the UITableViewController but it does not really scroll to the end - it seems like the UITableViewController starts to bounce way too early.

When I used the UITableViewController as the Root View Controller, everything worked fine, so I don't think there is something wrong with this ViewController.

The height of the CollectionView is pretty small, I just wanted to show the "bouncing" behaviour.

Here is the code for the collectionView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FeedSplitViewController : UIViewController, Controllable
{
    @IBOutlet weak var menuBar: MenuBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private var currentIndex = 0
    private var dragStart: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var feedActivities: FeedViewController!

    var controller: Controller!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initControls()
        self.initMenuBar()
        self.initCollectionView()
        self.initActivitiesViewController()
    }

    fileprivate func initActivitiesViewController()
    {
        self.feedActivities = UIStoryboard.instantiate("Main", "feedActivities")
        self.feedActivities.controller = self.controller
    }

    fileprivate func initControls()
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(false, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    }

    fileprivate func initMenuBar()
    {
        self.menuBar.showLine = true
        self.menuBar.enlargeIndicator = true
        self.menuBar.texts = [Resources.get("FEED_ACTIVITIES"), Resources.get("DASHBOARD")]

        self.menuBar.selectionChanged =
        {
            index in

            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.right, animated: true)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func initCollectionView()
    {
        self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        let menuBarFrame = self.menuBar.frame.origin
        let collectionView = self.collectionView.frame.origin

        Swift.print(menuBarFrame)
        Swift.print(collectionView)
    }
}

extension FeedSplitViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if indexPath.item == 0, let feedActivities = self.feedActivities
        {
            cell.contentView.addSubview(feedActivities.view)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        self.dragStart = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        let oldIndex = self.currentIndex

        let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width

        let currentPage = Int(round(page))

        if oldIndex != currentPage
        {
            if Settings.useHapticFeedback
            {
                Utilities.haptic(.medium)
            }

            self.menuBar.selectedIndex = currentPage
        }

        self.currentIndex = currentPage
    }
}
```

I have attached a small video: https://imgur.com/a/pj7l3Hd

Comment: what is the reason behind you offsetting the scrollview ? Is that necessary for you app ? perhaps this is where your issue lays?

Comment: This is just for testing purposes, in the final app the Table View will use the entire space. I have tried to use the entire space but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following:

- I no longer host the view of an ViewController directly in the
- Every UICollectionView cell hosts an UITableView.
- The UITableViewCell contains the data model that was previously implemented in the ViewController. The logic is still outside of the UITableViewCell.